# How to JAXB Unmarshal an integer into its enum equivalent?

Tags: java, xml, enums, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a class:

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class rootClass
{
    @XmlElement(name="test")
    public FeFiFo test;
}

enum FeFiFo
{
    FE,
    FI,
    FO,
}
```

And an XML:

```
<root>
  <test>1</test>
</root>
```

How can I unmarshal the XML into the class so that the `test` property becomes FeFiFo.FI? Currently it becomes null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an `XmlJavaTypeAdapter`

**rootClass**

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class rootClass
{
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EnumAdapter .class)
    @XmlElement(name="test")
    public FeFiFo test;
}
```

**adapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class EnumAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, FeFiFo>
{

    public FeFiFo unmarshal(String value) {
        //if()
        //else if()
        //else

        return FeFiFo.FE;
    }

    public String marshal(FeFiFo value) {
        //if()
        //else if()
        //else
        return "0";
    }

}
```

Comment: I like this a lot. Thanks. Any way to make it generic? I have multiple enums. ( I took a wack at it but couldn't get the `unmarshal` to call `E.values()[value]`.

Comment: Probably you could use the reflection to examine the enumerations in order to have only one xmladapter, but i have never tried it before.